# Get real time datas from external games

Tags: php, sql, request, external

I am creating a web application which gathering datas from external application like PC videos games.

My question is, how to get these datas?  Is there a "general" way to track these infos (like player statistics, in game players, ...) or do i have to find the right requests for each games ? Where can I find these kind of requests ? Is there any software which can help me ?

Here, an example of an unofficial website gathering datas from the game.
http://www.lolnexus.com/

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to grab data:

- Use the official API, some games provide API's where you could grab game data.
- Use network package sniffing
- Let users provide you information, like XFire.

There is no general way for grabbing game data since every game is different. Some methods may even violate the EULA. The best way to know how to gather data is simple; contact them.